# How can I kill a process safely in rust

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm creating a program that runs another one and send their outputs over the internet.
I have to run 2 threads to monitor `stdout` and `stderr`, but `Child` can only be owned by 1 process which means it is hard to tell whether the process has exited.
So I let one of the thread held the `Child` and let the other thread kills the other when exited:

```rust
let mut child_handle = Command::new("some_program")
        .current_dir("/some_dir")
        .stdout(Stdio::piped())
        .stderr(Stdio::piped());

    let mut child = child_handle.spawn().expect("Cannot run child process");

    let out = child.stdout.take().expect("Cannot take stdout");
    let err = child.stderr.take().expect("Cannot take stderr");

    let h1 = spawn(move || {
        let mut out = std::io::BufReader::new(out);
        let mut s = String::new();

        while let Ok(_) = out.read_line(&mut s) {
            if let Ok(Some(_)) = child.try_wait() {
                break;
            }

            println!("'{}'", s.strip_suffix('\n').unwrap());
            s = "".to_string();
        }
    });
    let h2 = spawn(move || {
        let mut out = std::io::BufReader::new(err);
        let mut s = String::new();

        while let Ok(_) = out.read_line(&mut s) {
            if !s.is_empty() {
                let ss = match s.strip_suffix('\n') {
                    None => { s }
                    Some(a) => { a.to_string() }
                };
                println!("'{}'", ss);
                s = "".to_string();
            }
        }
    });

    h1.join().unwrap();
    //TODO: kill h2
```

But both `JoinHandle` and `Thread` do not have a method to kill.
So how can I kill the process `h2`?

Comment: Wrap the `Child` in an `Arc<Mutex<>>` and pass that (or copies) around and ensure you can lock the mutex before manipulating the child process, like killing it.

Comment: [`Child::wait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.wait) will block until the child process terminates. There is also [`Child::try_wait`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Child.html#method.try_wait) if you want to check if the process has terminated without waiting for it to do so.

Comment: When the child exits, its `stdout` and `stderr` will be closed, so reading from them will return `EOF` (i.e. `Ok(0)`). So you can just check for that in both while loops: `while let Ok (len) = out.read_line (&mut s) { if len == 0 { break; } … }`

Comment: `h2` is *not* a process, it's a thread, there is no universal way to kill threads.